# Convert Date Object returned by angular 6 my-date-picker Module to Date type

Tags: angular6

I am using angular 6 my-date-picker module which returns an Object. I need to send the selected date to server side in a bean variable which is of Date type in angular. How can i do this.Any leads?

TS:

public myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
  };

// Initialized to specific date (09.10.2018).
   //public startDate: Date = { date: { year: 2018, month: 10, day: 9 } };

Comment: <my-date-picker name="startDate" [options]="myDatePickerOptions" placeholder="Select a date" [(ngModel)]="viewAuditSearchBean.startDate"></my-date-picker>

Comment: Above is my html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service that has a method that transforms the date:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DateService {

  constructor() { }

  transformToDate(fecha) {
    if ( fecha ) {
      return fecha.year + '-' + fecha.month + '-' + fecha.day;
    }
    return null;
  }

  transformToNgStructDate(fecha) {
    const t = fecha.split('-');
    return {
      year: parseInt(t[0], 0),
      month: parseInt(t[1], 0),
      day: parseInt(t[2].split('T')[0], 0)
    };
  }
}
```

Before sending the date to the server you must transform it with the function of the service.

You have a component that makes a request to the server passing the date, before you make the request you must apply the transformation.

For example:

```
const fch = this.dateService.transformToDate(date);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am new to my-datepicker. Could you please elaborate on how should i apply the above. I tried creating a function in ts but no luck

Comment: checking on the solution you provided. Will update!

Comment: transformToDate(fecha) function returned undefined. I am using mat date picker now and it is working as expected.